# Greasemonkey: Change text in a webpage?

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey

I used the function:

```
document.getElementsByTagName('strong')
```

to get all the text in a page with that type of formatting.  The HTML looks like:

```
<td align="center" valign="bottom"><H1><font size="+4"><strong>TEXT_HERE</strong></font> <br>
```

I would like to change "TEXT_HERE" to maybe something else or remove it all together.  How might I go about doing that?

Thanks in advance for your help :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

With a for loop?

```
var strongElems = document.getElementsByTagName('strong');
var wantToHide  = true || false;

for (var i=0; i<strongElems.length; i++)
{
  var thisElem = strongElems[i];
  if (wantToHide)
  {
    thisElem.style.display = "none"; // hide it
  }
  else
  {
    thisElem.textContent = "something else"; // change it
  }
}
```

Comment: the textContent did it :)  where do you find all the functions you can use to do snazzy stuff?  thanks :)

Comment: Google. :-D (SCNR). As far as documentation goes: For Firefox, the Mozilla Developer Center is the way to go, for IE basically everything is in the MSDN. The rest is in Google.

Answer (score 1):

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name           MyScript
// @namespace      http://example.com
// @description    Example
// @include        *
//
// @require     http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.1/jquery.min.js
// ==/UserScript==

var shouldHide = false;

$('strong').each(function() {
  if(shouldHide) {
    $(this).hide();
  } else {
    $(this).text("New Text");
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

When I wanted to change some text in a web page, I based my Greasemonkey solution on [DumbQuotes](http://diveintogreasemonkey.org/casestudy/dumbquotes.html).  I liked that I could easily define replacement pairs into a list:

```
replacements = {
  "old": "new",
  "foo": "bar",
};
```

That said, I'll check out Tomalak's solution as well.  Thanks for posting this question.